# chekbox validation not working in jquery when the checkbox inside the php foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, foreach

I am trying to check whether the checkbox is checked or not using jquery when the checkbox inside the php foreach loop.

i am trying to pass the checkbox value using php foreach loop values are passed correctly but cehckbox validations are not working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Checkbox Reference</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myform").submit(function(){
    valid = true;
    if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0)
    {
        alert ( "ERROR! Please select at least one checkbox" );
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form  name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="post" onSubmit="return validate();">
<?php
$values = array(1,2,3,4,5);
foreach($values as $id)
{
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checks[]' value='".$id."'><br>"; 
}

?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `.length` really what you want to check?

Comment: Just i want to validate this checkbox is checked or not when i submiting the form

Comment: Do you want to check if all of them were checked or at least one?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try as following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#myform").submit(function(e){
        if($('[name="checks[]"]:checked').length === 0) {
            alert ( "ERROR! Please select at least one checkbox" );
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });

});
```

Comment: Just put the `return valid` inside the `submit` handler, so if the form is invalid it will not be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery instead of $ symbol. with php the $ symbol may cause conflict . I have solved your issue.
 you can check here

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mtzq-yd1i

Answer (score 0):

i changed the code to this and it works:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e){
        valid = true;
        var inputs = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
        if(inputs.length == 0)
        {
            console.log ( "ERROR! Please select at least one checkbox" );
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    });
```

Try putting this code at the end of your html, even if you are using document.ready